# How to create such interface?

Tags: android, user-interface, interface

I'm thinking about an interface for my application, so i applied a GridView to have a dashboard like, BUT i'm not satisfied of the result, so i browsed some apps and found that this one have a very nice interface:
http://images.frandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/patiner.jpg
I would like to know if this is based on a GridView or simple button images or is there any other tips?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Please try to answer the question and not giving down votes!

Comment: Dunno, but it sure makes me homesick.

Comment: *"Please try [..]"* - great advice. That's exactly the reason you got a downvote from me. There are many ways to realize this. But you didn't try even one it seems. I won't reward your laziness by answering your question.

Comment: @alextsc: i tried with a gridview but had a bad result, that's why i posted that question to listen to your advice .

Comment: @androniennn Great. Next time please include that in your question. If I can see that in the first place, I won't downvote you.

Comment: @alextsc: so can you please try to purpose a solution? So i use simple buttons with `android:src=""` like bwoogie answered ? That would be perfect?

Comment: Can this be updated please to state the issue and what was initially tried? It would help searchers, and alextsc may remove a downvote :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you something like what you want. But I used regular buttons, you'll probably want image buttons. I just happened to have this code opened so i cut and pasted to make it more "example friendly" it might not be perfect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="2" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="2" />
            </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and just not giving down votes :). Anyway, this are just simple buttons, default android ones, how to make image buttons? Is there an XML code that can do it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, also if you are using the graphical editor they are in there as well. It's simple though, `<ImageButton src="@drawable/myimg" />`

Comment: Okay, i knew it however :p. Thanks :).